# Clean way of solving $\ln(x)=e^{-2x}$

Tags: calculus

I stumbled across this equation: $\ln(x)=e^{-2x}$

Is there a "proper" clean way of solving this, where i can isolate $x$ completely?

Thank you in advance

Comment: No, one can only write the solution in terms of a special function or give a numerical approximation. It's not hard to show, though, that there is precisely one solution, and that it's in $[1, 2]$.

Comment: I came across a problem similar to this a while ago. I set aside and never got back to it. @Travis -- how we can show the solution lies within that interval? Could you elaborate on that more or provide a link? I'm curious to see! Thanks!

Comment: $\text{ln}(x)$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$, and $\exp(-2x)$ a strictly decreasing one. Thus, there is at most one solution. If you find an interval $[a,b]$ such that $\text{ln}(a)<\exp(-2a)$ and $\text{ln}(b)>\exp(-2b)$, [you know your solution must lie in that interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Comment: @Mallory To elaborate on Wouter's explanation, we have $\ln 1 = 0 < e^{-2} = e^{-2(1)}$ but once we know that $2 < e < 4$ (which is easy to see using the Taylor expansion for $e$), we also have $\ln 2 = \frac{1}{2} \ln 4 > \frac{1}{2} > \frac{1}{e} > e^{-4}$. Both functions are continuous, so they assume the same value at some point in $(1, 2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first show there is a solution; consider
$$
f(x)=e^{-2x}-\ln x
$$
defined for $x>0$. We have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\infty,
\qquad
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty
$$
Thus a solution exists because of the intermediate value theorem.

Next we look at the number of solutions; clearly
$$
f'(x)=-2e^{-2x}-\frac{1}{x}<0
$$
so the function is decreasing. Hence the solution is unique.

In order to approximate it, you can consider the equation in the form $x=\exp(\exp(-2x))$ and define
$$
x_0=1,\quad x_{n+1}=\exp(\exp(-2x_n))
$$
Then
\begin{align}
x_0&=1 \\
x_1&=1.14492059268744918838\\
x_2&=1.10658925966289614831\\
x_3&=1.11555553271136164698\\
x_4&=1.11338956592476360904\\
x_5&=1.11390885833777776714\\
x_6&=1.11378413034903669438\\
x_7&=1.11381407546556892323\\
x_8&=1.11380688538603162150\\
x_9&=1.11380861174233198369
\end{align}
and the convergence is quite fast.

There is no “closed form” for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the $\ln(x)$ function or the exponential function by a power series. With this then you can solve for $x$. However it will only be an approximation. The more terms you expand a function the more accurate the solution will be.

Comment: I'm afraid this may not be an answer to the OP's question, since it sounds like he wants a closed form value for $x$.

Comment: I reckon, if it is not possible to isolate x completely and calculate it as a formula, an approximation would be fine. Do you mean like a limit where we can get closer and closer to the result as we increase a value?